# How to load a saved model into a new model class

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I worked with python and I save my trained model as follows `model.save("model.h5")`. Now I work with Pytorch and

Instead of pretrained resnet(described below), I would like to load a saved model `model.h5`, so what can I change in this code? meaning how can I load a `h5` model with `Pytorch' into a new model class

```
class ResNet(nn.Module):  
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2048, 3)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model.conv1(x)
        x = self.model.bn1(x)
        x = self.model.relu(x)
        x = self.model.maxpool(x)

        x = self.model.layer1(x)
        x = self.model.layer2(x)
        x = self.model.layer3(x)
        x = self.model.layer4(x)
        x = self.model.avgpool(x)

        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = nn.functional.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = nn.functional.softmax(self.fc2(x), dim=1)
        return x
```

I try to add those lines

```
class ResNet(nn.Module):  ####### load model
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        model = models.resnet50()
        self.model = model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model.h5))
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2048, 2048)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2048, 3) ....
```

But I find this error:

```
magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'H'.
```